# Joining tables without keys causes incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables - one master and the other lookup. both don't have any keys. The structure of the tables is below.

```
     first name last name   role     location   Compensation Level  state
      john       smith      Manager     LA         A                 CA
      john       smith      Manager     BOS        B                 MA
      super      smither    developer   LA         B                 CA
      tina       taylor     supervisor  SFO        A                 CA
      tina       taylor     supervisor  BOS        B                 MA


     first name  last name  role        dept        
     john         smith     manager     finance     
     john         smith     manager     hr      
     super        smither   developer   PA      
     tina         taylor    supervisor  HR      
     tina         taylor    supervisor  hr
```

very understandably, joining the two tables to get the dept for a first name, last name and role combination will result in incorrect results since there are other fields involved in the mix which identify a true unique record.

But given a structure like this, is there any way i can join the two tables to get the dept?

Using an inline subquery is not an option due to the way the final procedure is designed and due to other factors.

Any thoughts on this?

Expected output:

```
 first name last name   role     location   Compensation state dept
 john        smith      Manager    LA          A          CA finance
 john        smith      Manager    BOS         B          MA hr
 super       smither    developer  LA          B          CA PA
 tina        taylor     supervisor SFO         A          CA HR
 tina        taylor     supervisor  BOS        B          MA HR
```

Comment: Exactly how do you plan on doing that without any keys?  There's no way to tell which john smith is which there.  Same with tina taylor.

Comment: Simply no. It's not a matter of keys per se but that there is no way to uniquely identify the roles/departments. Table 2 needs discriminator that is also in table 1

Comment: In first row of your expected results, how do you know the first dept shouldn't be hr instead of finance? Tables are by definition unordered sets of rows.

Comment: @PeterSmith thanks for responding. Yes, that is what I thought - there is no way to identify a true unique record without keys or the other fields in the lookup table which makes it even more redundant.  I was pretty sure there is no way but thought I'd double check with experts here before i take it up to the powers be telling them why this cannot be done without a redesign.

Comment: @DanGuzman I don't and that is the challenge here with the current design. There is no way to tell if i am assigning the correct dept to the employee, unless the structures are redesigned.

Comment: this is a design issue. You need to resolve that. else there is no solution

Comment: Are there any other fields in those tables?  Anything at all from which you can infer which `john smith` in table 1 relates to which `john smith` from table 2?  If there is, then you can probably use `row_number()` to create surrogate keys on which to join.  But you ***must*** have some information on which to base that.  *(Data in tables don't have an order, so you can't say "the first john smith" because there is no concept of "first" in the data, it can easily change position at any moment.  this means that you Must make the determination based on data...)*

Comment: The fact that you can't use an inline sub-query makes no sense to me.  An inline sub-query is just a way of expressing certain logic in SQL *(Which is a declarative language, not an imperative language)*.  You could make a view consisting of numerous sub-queries, then select from the view; you'd be using sub-queries, but not be able to "see" them.  Something is wrong here, very wrong indeed.

Comment: Fire your development team.  Out of a cannon.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that gives deterministic results, but they're arbitrary results.  It's simply bases on determining an "ordered position" in each table, so that a choice can be made, and that choice be the same every time the query is executed, but there is no way to know that the choice is the correct one.

```
WITH
   sorted_t1 AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name, role
                               ORDER BY compensation_level, location, state)  AS discriminator
    FROM
        t1
)
,
   sorted_t2 AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name, role
                               ORDER BY dept)  AS discriminator
    FROM
        t2
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sorted_t1    t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
    sorted_t2    t2
        ON  t1.first_name    = t2.first_name
        AND t1.last_name     = t2.last_name
        AND t1.role          = t2.role
        AND t1.discriminator = t2.discriminator
```

***NOTES:***

This assumes a "case-insensitive" collation sequence.  Otherwise the `john smith` rows will never join *(as `'Manager'` wouldn't match `'manager'`)*

Similarly, the two `tina taylor` rows in table 2 are different *(`'hr'` vs `'HR'`)*, but if the collation sequence is case-insensitive it doesn't matter which gets joined to which, as there is no "material" difference between the rows.

It's also worth noting that in the example above there is no Real Reason to assume that the `'John Smith'` from LA is in `finance`.  The query simply forces that association because or the `ORDER BY` chosen in the `ROW_NUMBER()`.  This means that when using this technique you really should be using other fields, one's that ***mean*** something in relation to each other.